# Displaying a customized product SKU based on categories in shop and archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am mostly a designer and trying to wet my feet in PHP as it pertains to Wordpress.

I am using woocommerce and would like to display the SKU on the category pages. So far I have this:

```
//* add SKU to shop page

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shop_sku' );
function shop_sku(){
global $product;
echo '<span itemprop="productID" class="sku">SKU: ' . $product->sku . '<br></span>';
}
```

Works great. However my client would like to display a letter before the SKU depending on the category. Rather than go through and change all the SKU numbers, I thought it might make sense to add to the function.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shop_sku' );
function shop_sku(){
    global $product;
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ($product_cats == "Contemporary Modern Area Rugs") {
        echo '<span itemprop="productID" class="sku">SKU: C-' . $product->sku . '<br></span>';
    }

    elseif ($product_cats == "Traditional Oriental Area Rugs") {
        echo '<span itemprop="productID" class="sku">SKU: T-' . $product->sku . '<br></span>';
    }

    else {
        echo '<span itemprop="productID" class="sku">SKU: S-' . $product->sku . '<br></span>';  
    }
}
```

My problem is that only the third condition is met, meaning all the SKU numbers display with an "S-" in front.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `var_dump`ing `$product_cats`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I just tried that...no luck.

Comment: That means that $product_cats is empty, thus it isn't "Contemporary Modern Area Rugs" or "Traditional Oriental Area Rugs". You'll need to figure out why it's coming back empty. Does `get_the_ID()` return a valid ID? If so, what is breaking inside `wp_get_post_terms`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I just came to that same conclusion...I did figure out that (I think) I need to have ID numbers, which I did get. So "Contemporary Modern Area Rugs" had an id of 12, but that is empty as well. I think I'm close, I just don't know enough to get there...

Comment: Thank you so much LoicTheAztec. Works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is better to use the native conditional function **`has_term()`** with the category slugs or IDs.

I have customized your code a little:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shop_sku' );
function shop_sku(){
    global $post, $product;

    //It's better to REPLACE the category name by the slug or the ID !!!

    if ( !has_term( 'Contemporary Modern Area Rugs', 'product_cat' ) && !has_term( 'Traditional Oriental Area Rugs', 'product_cat' ) )
        $letter = 'S';

    if ( has_term( 'Contemporary Modern Area Rugs', 'product_cat' ) )
        $letter = 'C';

    if ( has_term( 'Traditional Oriental Area Rugs', 'product_cat' ) )
        $letter = 'T';

    echo '<span itemprop="productID" class="sku">SKU: '. $letter .'-' . $product->sku . '<br></span>';
}
```

*Naturally, this goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**This code is tested and works.**

---

Reference: [**WordPress Function has_term()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)